# C# deserializator doesn't return result

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor

i have problem with my deserialization and don't know how to deal.

```
 var jsonString = @"
            {
              ""Result"": [
                {
                  ""Id"": 994,
                  ""Name"": ""LL Bottom Bracket"",
                },
                {
                  ""Id"": 995,
                  ""Name"": ""ML Bottom Bracket"",
                }
              ]
            }";
```

HotelRoomDTO class looks like:

```
public class HotelRoomDTO
{

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

And Service is

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<HotelRoomDTO>> GetHotelRooms(string checkInDate, string checkOutDate)
{

    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
    };
    var response = await _client.GetAsync($"api/hotelroom?checkInDate={checkInDate}&  checkOutDate={checkOutDate}");
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var rooms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<HotelRoomDTO>>(content, settings);
    return rooms;
}
```

When i try to  run app deserializator crash and doesnt return result. I think that problem is in this "Result"  list of objects.When it doesnt exist everithing works fine but when i get data from real Db and try to deserialize it automatic adds this "Result" and code doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure it returns an `IEnumerable<HotelRoomDTO>`?

Comment: Crash is a pretty bad description of an error. What exception with what error message do you get?

Comment: Assuming, the extra quotes `""` are just typos here, your JSON string describes an `object` (note the curly braces `{}` at the beginning and end), yet you try to deserialize it into an `IEnumberable` (what would be a JSON array with `[]` in the beginning and end). You need to deserialize to a class with a `IEnumerable <HotelRoomDTO> Result {get;set;}` property

Comment: @derpirscher C# has verbatim string literals `@"..."` where double quotes contained in the string need to be escaped with another double quote so that `""` becomes `"` within the actual string value.

Comment: @phuzi I try it. When again try to serialize with cast result to (IEnumerable<HotelRoomDTO>), because without that i have error again doesn't have respond from serializer

Comment: @phuzi i found another solution removing "Result" and then deserialzie. Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You can try a creting a Root class:

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("Result")]
    public List<HotelRoomDTO> Result { get; set; }

}
```

And deserialize him:

```
var rooms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonString, settings);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are receiving a list of "HotelRoomDTOs", but your model is only made for one.

Diego's answer would work on this occasion. What you want to do is the following. Change your model file to the following:

```
public class Result
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HotelRoomDTO
{
   public List<Result> Result { get; set; }
}
```

In your `GetHotelRooms` function you now change

```
var rooms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<HotelRoomDTO>>(content, settings);
```

to

```
var rooms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HotelRoomDTO>(content, settings);
```

The variable `rooms` is now a list filled with HotelRoomDTOs.

[image: Showcase]

Answer (score 0):

I found simplest solution i removed "Result" because i dont need it and after that desialize.Thank you for another answers.

```
var result = JObject.Parse(content)["Result"].ToString(Formatting.None);
var rooms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<HotelRoomDTO>>(content);
```